# Transposing only few columns with multiple unique id.var using recast()

Tags: r, reshape2

I need to transpose my data in a certain way. I am going to explain it using an example:

Here is the data:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1335724903, 1335724903, 1335724903, 1335724903), 
                                     class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                    a = c("UC 2", "UC 2", "UC 2", "UC 2"), b = c("50300", "50300", "50300", "50300"), 
                    c = c("40", "40", "40", "40"), d = c("ISO_A","ISO_A", "ISO_B", "ISO_C"), e = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                    f = c(45, 45, 45, 45), g = c(0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024)), 
               .Names = c("Date",  "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Same data but just in better format so we can better see what i mean by "transposing in certain way":

```
               Date    a     b  c     d e  f     g
1 2012-04-29 20:41:43 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_A 2 45 0.024
2 2012-04-29 20:41:43 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_A 2 45 0.024
3 2012-04-29 20:41:43 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_B 2 45 0.024
4 2012-04-29 20:41:43 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_C 2 45 0.024
```

**So from this table, i would like to get a table like this:**

```
    a     b  c     d e  f  ISO_A  ISO_B  ISO_C
1 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_A 2 45  0.024  0.024  0.024
```

At the moment i got stuck with this piece of code:

```
data2 <- recast(data, a + b + c +d + e + f + variable ~ d, id.var = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), fun.aggregate=mean)
```

which results in slightly different table which i need:

```
     a     b  c     d e  f variable        ISO_A        ISO_B        ISO_C
1 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_A 2 45    Date 1.335725e+09          NaN          NaN
2 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_A 2 45       g 2.400000e-02          NaN          NaN
3 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_B 2 45    Date          NaN 1.335725e+09          NaN
4 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_B 2 45       g          NaN 2.400000e-02          NaN
5 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_C 2 45    Date          NaN          NaN 1.335725e+09
6 UC 2 50300 40 ISO_C 2 45       g          NaN          NaN 2.400000e-02
```

Any ideas how i can improve it?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); data %>% group_by(Date) %>% unique() %>% spread(d, g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dcast` on the `unique` 'data'

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(unique(data), ...~d, value.var="g", mean)
#                 Date    a     b  c e  f ISO_A ISO_B ISO_C
#1 2012-04-30 00:11:43 UC 2 50300 40 2 45 0.024 0.024 0.024
```